# Why does ngDirective `template` allow for correct `clientHeight` but `templateUrl` gives 0

Tags: javascript, angularjs, d3.js, svg, dagre-d3

**TL/DR**

[plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UFXHlvtdreXtMIJmPacl?p=preview)

```
// Foreign object is the right size
template: "<h1>{{name}}</h1>",
```

but

```
// Foreign object is size 0 why is that?
templateUrl: "dialog.html",
```

**FULL**

I have a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/UFXHlvtdreXtMIJmPacl?p=preview) that demos what I am talking about. I am using a d3 library called dagreD3. It creates a foreign object in an svg using the following code...

```
function addHtmlLabel(root, node) {
  var fo = root
            .append("foreignObject")
            .attr("width", "100000");

  var div = fo
    .append("xhtml:div");

  var label = node.label;
  switch(typeof label) {
    case "function":
      div.insert(label);
      break;
    case "object":
      // Currently we assume this is a DOM object.
      div.insert(function() { return label; });
    break;
      default: div.html(label);
  }

  util.applyStyle(div, node.labelStyle);
  div.style("display", "inline-block");
  // Fix for firefox
  div.style("white-space", "nowrap");

  // IMPORTANT AREA
  var w, h;
  div
    .each(function() {
      w = this.clientWidth;
      h = this.clientHeight;
    });

  fo
    .attr("width", w)
    .attr("height", h);

  return fo;
}
```

Now the problem I am having is when I run the following code...

```
$scope.nodes = d3.range(20).map(function() {
  // IMPORTANT AREA
  var i = Math.floor(Math.random() * types.length),
      rand = types[i],
      nScope = $rootScope.$new();
  nScope.name = rand.label;
  var element = angular.element('<jg-item name="name"></jg-item>');
  $compile(element)(nScope);
  // END AREA
  return {
    radius: Math.random() * 36 + 10,
    label: element[0],
    labelType: "html",
    color: rand.color,
    typeIndex: i,
    radius: 50,
    shape: rand.shape ? rand.shape : "rect"
  };
});
```

Then if I have this in the directive...

```
// This works
template: "<h1>{{name}}</h1>"
```

Everything looks great but when I move the HTML out to an external file and import like this...

```
// This fails
templateUrl: "dialog.html",
```

Then the HTML is properly rendered but the foreign object has a width and height of 0.

What explains this (assuming it is with the digest cycle) and is there a way I can get around this limitation?

```
template: $templateCache.get("...")
```

?

Answer (score 0):

Apperently I was right this is hacky but seems to [fix it](https://plnkr.co/edit/2fPMm4cfEgviNIXZ0ELw)...

```
$templateCache.put('test.html', '<h1>{{name}}</h1>');
...
template:$templateCache.get("test.html"),
```

Then it works. This solution is acceptable because I am already using HTML2JS to load these items into the cache.